# Variable is declaired in {} but gives out the Error

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

This above is the error which is written in VSCode.

```
  getGlobalData(){
    return this.http.get(this.globalDataUrl, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      map(result => {
        let data: GlobalDataSummary[] = [];
        let raw = {}
        let rows = result.split('\n');
        rows.splice(0, 1);
        // console.log(rows);
        rows.forEach(rows => {
          let cols = rows.split(/,(?=\S)/)

          let cs = {
            country: cols[3],
            confirmed: +cols[7],
            deaths: +cols[8],
            recovered: +cols[9],
            active: +cols[10],
          };
          let temp: GlobalDataSummary = raw[cs.country];
          if (temp){
            temp.active = cs.active + temp.active
            temp.confirmed = cs.confirmed + temp.confirmed
            temp.deaths = cs.deaths + temp.deaths
            temp.recovered = cs.recovered + temp.recovered

            raw[cs.country] = temp;
          }else{
            raw[cs.country] = cs;
          }
        })
        console.log(raw);
        

        return [];
      })
    )
  }
```

The raw[cs.country] is constantly underlined in red.

Hope someone can help me out :-) Thanks in the front!

Comment: From where cs coming? And is it strongly typed model? if not declare cs as any. It won't throw error then.

Comment: Im editing the code line - one moment!

Comment: I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

```
let cs = {
        country: cols[3],
        confirmed: +cols[7],
        deaths: +cols[8],
        recovered: +cols[9],
        active: +cols[10],
      } as any; //adding as any will not throw error while using the property.
```

declare it as any and it would not show that error again. or create an interface before to assign value in it. but the first one is the shortest solution.